# Splash Screen scrolling up after about one second with phonegap 3.0.0 in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, splash-screen

I've a problem with iOS splashscreen I use phonegap 3.0.0, jquery mobile, backbone.
My config.xml out of www folder is:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="true" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
```

in index.html I've

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        
        // Cordova is ready
        
        function onDeviceReady() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                       }, 2000);
            
        }
</script>
```

For first second I've fullscreen splashsreen

[image: splashscreen 1]

for the next two seconds, splashscreen scroll up about 20px

[image: splashscreen 2]

I have tested it in all iOS simulator:iPhone, iPhone retina, iPhone retina 4-inch...
and in iOS 5.1/7.0

Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to update to 3.1, they've fixed the splash screen plugin at that level to resolve this issue.

Or check our this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001535/phonegap-ios7-splash-screen-bar-on-bottom-when-loading)

Comment: I have create a new project with cordova 3.1 and it's all ok!

Comment: Ive noticed an issue with 3.1 that I've reported when some plugins do not get mapped to each project and cause issues, mainly iOS for some reason. I had it happen to me and had to recreate my ios project